# Secure Elasticsearch with Apache 2.4

Tags: security, apache-2.4, elasticsearch, ubuntu-16.04

I have an Elasticsearch 1.7.5 instance running on a Ubuntu 16.04 server that I need to test after opening it up to the internet. I know you can use Mod Rewrite on Apache to lock down HTTP request methods (PUT, GET, POST, etc).

I can currently access my Elasticsearch instance through http://example.com/es/ which I've configured a proxy for, in Apache.

I want to disable the PUT, DELETE and TRACE methods entirely. I want to leave GET open, but restrict POST to the search call (http://example.com/es/_search).

My current Mod Rewrite rules are:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^(POST|GET)\ /.*\ HTTP/1\.1$ 
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Which I know will only allow the POST and GET methods.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/protecting-your-data-in-elasticsearch?ultron=protecting-your-data-in-elasticsearch-webinar&blade=invite&hulk=email) would be of a help?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'd prefer to get this sorted out a bit sooner than then, but I'll definitely take a look.